existence of longish cycle in random permutation
It is well known that a random permutation on $n$ points has a giant cycle (a cycle of length $> 0.5n$) with probability approaching $\ln(2)$ as $n$ tends to infinity.
Are there similar results for shorter cycles? In particular, does the probability of having a cycle of length at least $0.01n$ tend to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity?

I do not see how the probability for a random permutation of $1, \ldots, n$ to have a cycle of length $>n/2$ approaches $\ln 2$ as $n$ grows indefinitely. How would you go about proving  that? Instead, this probability should converge to $1/2,$ since the length of the largest cycle normalised by $n$ converges to a uniform $(0, 1)$ law.

@MeroWingz length of cycle containing $1$ (or any given element) is uniform. Probability of having cycle of length $\geq n / 2$ is $H_n - H_{n / 2}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4468695/659499

Let $P_{n, k}$ be probability of longest cycle in permutation of $n$ elements to have length at most $k$. For example, $P_{n, n / 2 - 1} \approx 1 - \ln 2$.
We have of course $P_{n, k} = 1$ if $k > n$ and $P_{n, k} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k \frac{1}{n} \cdot P_{n - i, k}$ ($1$ is in cycle of length $i$, and the rest elements form a random permutation on $n - i$ elements).
From this it's easy to see that $P_{n, k}$ monotonically decreases in $n$ for any $k$: $P_{n + 1, k} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k \frac{1}{n + 1} \cdot P_{n + 1 - i, k} \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{n} \cdot P_{n - i, k} = P_{n, k}$.
Thus $P_{n, k} \geq \frac{k}{2n} \cdot P_{n - k / 2, k}$ (take last $k / 2$ terms of the sum).
If $n = \frac{m}{2} \cdot k$, this gives
$$P_{n, k} \geq \\
\frac{1}{m} \cdot P_{\frac{m - 1}{2}\cdot k, k} \geq \\
\frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{m - 1} P_{\frac{m - 2}{2} \cdot k, k} \geq \\
\ldots \\
\frac{1}{m!} \cdot P_{0, k} = \frac{1}{m!}$$
So, for any constant $\alpha > 0$, probability of having no cycles of length greater than $\alpha n$, is separated from $0$.
